# Как обозначается абсолютно любой символ в RegExp?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно получить строку данные между ```` ``` ````:

Как пример из строки

````
```
Я пожилой
Дракон
```
````

мне нужно получить "`Я пожилой\nДракон`".
Для этой задачи я использую RegExp. Как в них обозначить абсолютно любой символ, даже с `\n`?

Comment: Любой символ - это [\w|\W]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если вы используете регулярное выражение в среде, поддерживающей стандарт ECMAScript 2018+**, вы можете использовать `.` для поиска любого символа вместе с [флагом `s`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.dotAll).

````js
const text = '```\nЯ пожилой\nДракон\n```';
const regex = /```(.*?)```/gs;
console.log( Array.from(text.matchAll(regex), (x) => x[1].trim()) )
````

Я использовал `String#matchAll` и регулярное выражение с захватывающей подмаской, так как левый и правый разделители совпадают (```` ``` ````). Иначе можно было бы использовать выражение с блоками просмотра назад/вперёд и `String#match`: ```` text.match(/(?<=```\s*).*?(?=\s*```)/gs) ```` (это не сработает, если в строке больше одного  совпадения).

**Если нужна поддержка любого стандарта ECMAScript, можно использовать `[^]`**:

````js
var text = '```\nЯ пожилой\nДракон\n```';
var regex = /```([^]*?)```/g;
var arr=[],m;
while(m = regex.exec(text)) {
  arr.push(m[1].trim())
}
console.log(arr);
````

Кроме того, можно использовать `[\s\S]`, `[\d\D]` или `[\w\W]` для поиска любого символа. Эти конструкции менее эффективны, однако их можно использовать в тех случаях, когда выражения могут быть использованы не только в среде JavaScript, так как они поддерживаются во всех регулярных выражениях NFA.

Answer (score 0):

Любой символ - это `[\w|\W]`, благодаря комментарию [@xmikex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1346679/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2-re/1346698?noredirect=1#comment2386066_1346679).

Comment: `[\w|\W]` - это не совсем то.

Answer (score -3):

```
const str = `Я пожилой\\n\Дракон`;  
const text = `Я пожилой Дракон`.split(' Дракон').join('\\n\Дракон');
```

[Спецсимволы](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#spetssimvoly)

В javaScript если нет переноса визуально, то он есть не визуально.
Пример -

```js
const test = `Тут 
Есть
перенос
строки`.split('\n')

console.log(test);
```